# Single data dictionary in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I have what seems to me like a simple problem. I have an array of values that I need to loop and delete. The problem is that an array can only be redimmed (cant delete the element in the middle).

I was contemplating using a dictionary, but I would not really use the value, only the key, which seems like a waste... **Is there such thing as a "key" list?**

For context, what I would like to do is something like:

1. Create array: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`
2. Delete an element from the middle: e.g. delete(3) = `{1,2,4,5,6,7}`

**As I said, I can use a dictionary, but seems like a waste!**

Comment: Just put a blank value in as an item. You can return the Keys as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardly ever put values in a dictionary. I just use keys. Don't worry about it. No data uses no memory.

These are your options.

**From .NET** (try to avoid these as there is already the COM overhead -  the .NET overhead as well just duplicates COM functionality)

> •**ArrayList**—An array class that doesn't have a fixed size. You can just keep adding items to it.
>
> •**Hashtable**—This class is similar to the Scripting.Dictionary class. You can add items and look them up by key.
>
> •**Queue**—This is a first in, first out (FIFO) collection. You push items in, and then read them out at a later time in the same order.
>
> •**Stack**—A first-in, last out (FILO) collection. You push items onto the stack, and then pop them off in reverse order.
>
> •**SortedList**—Similar to the Hashtable, except when you iterate through the items,n they're always sorted by the key.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719110(v=vs.71).aspx

**COM Objects**

You have VBScript's Scripting.Runtime's **Dictionary** (vbscript is pastable into VBA)

```
'This dedups
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
Dict.Add "Key1", "Data"
Dict.Add "Key2", "Data"
Dict.Add "Key3", "Data"
If Err.Number <> 0 then
    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then
        Dict.Remove Line
        Dict.Add Line, ""
    End If
End If
For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
    Msgbox thing
Next
```

Then there is the **ADO Recordset**, which can be saved and loaded from file.

```
'This sorts and filters
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
.Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
.Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
.Open
.AddNew
.Fields("SortKey").value = 1
.Fields("Txt").value = "Line1"
.UpDate
.AddNew
.Fields("SortKey").value = 2
.Fields("Txt").value = "Line2"
.UpDate
.AddNew
.Fields("SortKey").value = 3
.Fields("Txt").value = "Line3"
.UpDate

'Sorting
.Sort = "SortKey ASC"

'Filtering
.filter = "Sortkey < 3"

'Writing it out
Do While not .EOF
    MsgBox .Fields("Txt").Value
    .MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use an ArrayList**:

```
Set myAl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")        
myAl.Add ("The") 'Add Item
myAl.Add ("dog") 'Add Item
myAl.Remove ("dog") 'Remove an item

'An example of how to traverse the items of an ArrayList:
For Each Item In myAl
    Debug.Print Item
Next Item
```

You might just as well use the `Dictionary` and I don't expect that there will be a lot of overhead, nevertheless, the `ArrayList` data structure is probably the one you are looking for.

There are other data structures like Hashtables, Stacks, Queues but they seem less appropriate for your need.